# ¿Cómo implementar un trigger para actualizar un stock de productos al borrar una venta?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, trigger, sql-server-2012

Tengo estás 3 tablas y este trigger

```
CREATE TABLE Producto 
(  cod_bar char(13) NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  stock SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pkProducto_cod_bar PRIMARY KEY (cod_bar)  ) 
 GO

CREATE TABLE Venta (
  id_Venta int IDENTITY (1,1),
  fecha date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pkVenta_id_Venta PRIMARY KEY (id_Venta)) 
  go

CREATE TABLE Detalle_Venta 
  (
  cod_bar char(13) NOT NULL,
  id_Venta int NOT NULL, 
  cantidad tinyint NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT pkDetalleVenta PRIMARY KEY (cod_bar, id_Venta),
  CONSTRAINT fkDet_cod_bar foreign key (cod_bar) REFERENCES Producto(cod_bar),
  CONSTRAINT fkDet_id_Venta foreign key (id_Venta) REFERENCES Venta(id_Venta)
  )
  go

CREATE TRIGGER A_Venta 
ON Detalle_Venta
  AFTER Delete
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @cod_bar char(13), @CANTIDAD INT, @ID_VENTA INT
  SELECT @cod_bar = [cod_bar], @CANTIDAD = [cantidad], @ID_VENTA = [ID_VENTA]
  FROM DELETED

   UPDATE Producto 
   set stock = ((SELECT STOCK FROM Producto WHERE cod_bar=@cod_bar) + (@CANTIDAD))
  where cod_bar=@cod_bar
END
GO
```

Lo que quería hacer es que al borra registros de la tabla detalle_venta mediante un where la cantidad de productos borrados se regresará al stock de la tabla producto. Pero por ejemplo si hago un delete en  detalle_venta en el id_venta=1 y este tiene 2 o más registros el trigger solo me actualiza 1 producto y ocupo que se actualicen todos los que borre.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que puedes implementar un `trigger` como el siguiente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER A_Venta 
ON Detalle_Venta
  AFTER Delete
AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE Producto
    set stock = stock + D.cantidad
    FROM Producto P
    INNER JOIN (SELECT cod_bar, 
                       SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad
                       FROM DELETED D
                       GROUP BY cod_bar
         ) D
         ON D.cod_bar = P.cod_bar

END
GO
```

Lo que hacemos es simplemente una consulta de actualización, sobre las filas eliminadas, obtenemos la suma de `cantidad` por cada `cod_bar` y luego actualizamos este valor en el `stock` de cada `Producto` coincidente.

Comment: Lo intentare gracias